# How to get max value of particular column in array in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a array named checkdata:

```
[{"name:"aasha","id":"1","age":"25","address":"happay appartment"},
 {"name:"megha","id":"2","age":"21","address":"viajy nagar"},
 {"name:"sujeet","id":"11","age":"38","address":"pb road"}]
```

Now what i want is to get max value of id that is 11 in above example array and store it in variable.
I have worked on same thing in php using 
max(array_column($checkdata['details'], 'id')); .Can any one help to make it work in angular js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a sort method that would place the highest id as first

```
var arr = [{"name":"aasha","id":"1","age":"25","address":"happay appartment"},{"name":"megha","id":"2","age":"21","address":"viajy nagar"}, {"name":"sujeet","id":"11","age":"38","address":"pb road"}];

var highestId = arr.sort(function(a, b){
    return parseInt(b.id) - parseInt(a.id);
})

console.log(highestId[0])
```

You can also use the map method which would do a similar thing to the above sort but would only return an array of integers with no sort

```
var items =  arr.map(function(o) { return parseInt(o.id); })
```

However you can then execute the Math.max method on the array to retrieve the highest value:

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, items);
```

```js
var arr = [{"name":"aasha","id":"1","age":"25","address":"happay appartment"},{"name":"megha","id":"2","age":"21","address":"viajy nagar"}, {"name":"sujeet","id":"11","age":"38","address":"pb road"}];

var highestId = arr.sort(function(a, b){
 return parseInt(b.id) - parseInt(a.id);
})

console.log(highestId[0].id)

var items =  arr.map(function(o) { return parseInt(o.id); })
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, items);

console.log(max)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the missing quote after `name` property is a typo. You can try following

You can use simple Javascript to get max value. Use `Number` to convert string value of `id` to number and `Array.reduce` to get the maximum value.

```js
var arr = [{"name":"aasha","id":"1","age":"25","address":"happay appartment"},
 {"name":"megha","id":"2","age":"21","address":"viajy nagar"},
 {"name":"sujeet","id":"11","age":"38","address":"pb road"}];
 
var id = arr.reduce((a,{id}) => Number(id) > a ? Number(id) : a , -1);
console.log(id);
```